# Parsing out all timestamps in RSS feed using feedparser

Tags: python, date, time, feedparser

I am fairly new to the feedparser lib in Python.

Trying to parse out a complete list of timestamps from a RSS feed, I currently have:

```
import feedparser
from time import gmtime, strftime

d = feedparser.parse('http://www.bloomberg.com/feed/podcast/taking-stock.xml')
dPub = d.entries[0].published   # out: u'Mon, 06 May 2013 08:19:36 -0400'
dPubPretty = strftime(dPub, gmtime())
print dPubPretty    # out: Mon, 06 May 2013 08:19:36 -0400

# loop over d.entries[0:] - ???
# for all d.entries...

d.entries[1].published  # out: u'Mon, 06 May 2013 08:16:15 -0400'
d.entries[2].published  # out: u'Fri, 03 May 2013 09:01:50 -0400'
```

I'd like to loop over all d.entries and output a list of timestamps, so with strftime() applied, the output would be something like:

```
# output goal:
Mon, 06 May 2013 08:19:36 -0400
Mon, 06 May 2013 08:16:15 -0400
Fri, 03 May 2013 09:01:50 -0400
...
```

**Referencing these docs**:

feedparser - Content Normalization: http://pythonhosted.org/feedparser/content-normalization.html#advanced-normalization

time - Time access and conversions: http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime

Answer (score 2):

Try to iterate over each entry

```
import feedparser
from time import gmtime, strftime

d = feedparser.parse('http://www.bloomberg.com/feed/podcast/taking-stock.xml')

for entry in d.entries:
    dPub = entry.published  
    dPubPretty = strftime(dPub, gmtime())
    print dPubPretty
```

You will get the following output:

```
Mon, 06 May 2013 08:19:36 -0400
Mon, 06 May 2013 08:16:15 -0400
Fri, 03 May 2013 09:01:50 -0400
Fri, 03 May 2013 08:57:55 -0400
Fri, 03 May 2013 08:54:21 -0400
Thu, 02 May 2013 10:04:42 -0400
Thu, 02 May 2013 09:38:42 -0400
...
Mon, 18 Mar 2013 08:03:27 -0400
Mon, 18 Mar 2013 08:01:21 -0400
```

Comment: You don't need `range(len(d.entries))`; you can simply do `for i in d.entries:` and then `dPub = i.published`

Comment: Both of the above, full script by jabaldonedo and comment by B. Khalid, are exactly what I needed, and they both work (tested)! Khalid's update makes the script a bit shorter... Thanks to both so much.